# sudo won't read file at /etc/profile.d/*.sh

Tags: sudo

I just create a file at `/etc/profile.d/texlive.sh` where I export paths from textlive. When I log as root `tlgmr` is in path, when I log as normal user too but when I doo `sudo tlmgr install xelatex` I complains that command tlmgr was not found

How can I make sudo read `/etc/profile` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [answer for /etc/profile not sourced for `sudo su`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327551/etc-profile-not-sourced-for-sudo-su#327553)

> "Only login shells source /etc/profile"

So you may need to do

```
sudo -i             # Login shell for superuser
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't now that only login shells source /etc/profile, so this problem extends to crontab and other things